# Bizarre red / orange alert bar has appeared ? What's up?

Tags: support

A bizarre orange alert bar has appeared, telling me I have a message, am in trouble for swearing, or must make a payment, or something

[image]

What in fact is the message or alert, and what should I do ??

As far as I know I don't owe any money, and I haven't sworn much lately.

If I have a pm or something I want to get it. Pls help

--

I've just realised the alert color in question is, indeed, the same hex color as the "META logo color".

Does this mean the alert is telling me I have a message or something, on, the Meta site?

Comment: It is part of the design.

Comment: On Main it is orange, on Meta it is grey. So you always know where you are...

Comment: well - the "corporate color" of meta (notice the small "META" tag-like logo) is indeed ............... that color.  so that's not right.  (You can actually see that on the image I pasted in.)

Comment: Your freehand circles are both poorly rendered and grossly colored.

Comment: hi @Will what "circles" are you referring to?

Comment: Wait - were you trying to make a joke? Oh, sorry.

Comment: If you use uBlock Origin, the following filter gets rid of it: `stackoverflow.com##header.so-header:style(border-top: 0px #000000)`

Comment: I appreciate you telling me that @JackManey, cheers

Comment: it looks like the site is 99% and still loading or something...

Answer (score 1):

It's not an alert, both are simply part of the design. The top line is there unconditionally, the line under *Questions* indicates that you are currently on the *Questions* page.

Comment: Hmm .. thanks but .. are we talking about the same thing?  It's an alert indicator.  It's exactly the color of an alert indicator.  it's in exactly the position of an alert indicator.  What else can it be but an alert indicator?

Comment: notice, indeed, it's the same color, design, weight, etc, as the other alert indicators on the page (eg, "icon numbers" alert indicators)

Comment: Your arrows are pointing to the two horizontal lines in the screenshot, that's what you are talking about, right? It's not an alert indicator.

Comment: erm ... oke just not something we are used too but its cool