# Orange stripe in the new top bar looks distractingly like a loading progress bar

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-bar

**This is not a duplicate of [Bizarre red / orange alert bar has appeared ? What's up?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343753/bizarre-red-orange-alert-bar-has-appeared-whats-up) because it is a discussion of a design concern, not a support request.**

Some websites (e.g. GitHub, YouTube) use a small coloured stripe at the top of the page to indicate that something is loading.

Stack Overflow is not one of those sites. But with the new top bar, every time I switch to a Stack Overflow tab, the orange stripe makes me subconsciously do a double-take. I quickly conclude that nothing is actually loading, but I've already been distracted so the damage is done.

I don't know if this is something that will wear off over time, but for now it adds a lot of subtle friction to using SO as a reference.

Comment: Looking at that bar actually brings me a tiny bit of stress. Why would one include a "border" that looks like a nearly-finished progress bar into one's site design? In what universe could this possibly make sense?

Comment: I love the new bar

Comment: What orange stripe?

Comment: I wish the fake coloured-stripe progress bars would be the ones to go away instead. The orange here looks nice.

Comment: I find myself subconsciously flicking my mouse wheel to scroll up when I'm already at the top of the page because I seem to have trained myself to stop scrolling once I see the black stripe of the old top bar. I guess it will wear off over time.

Comment: I find myself really liking the new top bar.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a subtle 1 pixel high shadow under the bar when you are not scrolled to the top of the page that disappears when you are at the top and can stop scrolling. Perhaps a little *too* subtle. Overall I like the new bar though.

Comment: I dug around in uBlock Origin enough to figure out a filter that gets rid of the bullshit border! `stackoverflow.com##header.so-header:style(border-top: 0px #000000)`

Comment: I would not say this is a progress bar on a web site. Firefox mobile has this 2 or 3 pixel page loading progress bar for all sites and it is exactly the same color as the 3px border of the <header> element. When loading SO in firefox mobile over a not-so-fast connection, it is hard to see when the page is completely loaded.

Comment: I recommend adding a screenshot of the orange bar to help demontrate

Comment: @samgak It seems that that shadow is now always active.